# "A" key on keyboard sends 0-3 keystrokes

Tags: keyboard

When I press the "A" key on my laptop, I may get "", "a", "aa", or "aaa" appearing in the input window. The "s" and "d" keys have the same problem to a lesser degree.

I've tried playing with keyboard in the control panel, by altering Lowering the repeat delay and rate do not solve the problem. One oddity I noticed was in the device manager:

[image: four keyboards]

It's a little weird that the laptop says it has four keyboards when there is only one physical keyboard attached. But if that were the source of the issue, I would expect it to affect all keys equally. It does not. For example, the "p" key works just fine.

I also tried enabling FilterKeys "to ignore brief or repeated keystrokes." No help. Then I tried BounceKeys. It DOES fix the problem. However, the shortest delay I can set in BounceKeys is 0.3 seconds. That's too long! For example, when typing "too" just now, it came out as "to" because my natural typing speed for the "oo" is less than a 0.3 second delay.

I think Bounce Keys at 0.1 seconds would fix my problem. But I don't see a way to do that.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: My computer is an HP ZBook laptop. It is still under warranty. Sending it away is an option. I was hoping to avoid that, but maybe I can't.

Comment: This is a typical hardware issue.  Try cleaning your keyboard, you've probably got crumbs or hairs or other debris stuck under the affected keys.

Comment: Chances are the keyboard is faulty and when pressing the key it is quickly making and breaking contact. It would be worth Googling "<laptop model> replacement keyboard".

Comment: Just test with a borrowed USB keyboard. If that works, it's a hardware issue. Replacement keyboards are usually in expensive and easy to install.

Comment: It's called 'key chatter', just FYI. And yep, it's a common hardware issue. Please update your question with, what hardware you're working on. For instance, the Macbook Pro butterfly-keys are widely known to have problems with it. So much, so Apple have made a [Keyword service program](https://support.apple.com/keyboard-service-program-for-mac-notebooks), making it free to get it repaired/replaced.